# How to stop text overflowing into the another div while maintaining exact div ratios?

Tags: css

I have the following requirements

1. The two boxes on the left should always be 50/50 split
2. The Image on the right should stretch to accommodate the text height on the left
3. The text on the left should never clip, the box should just enlarge to fit the text

Right now the problem is that the text on the top overflows into the bottom div like this

[image]

I've added sample code to show this problem

```css
.section-8 {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
}

.div-block-230 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div-block-231 {
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #06c;
}

.div-block-232 {
  width: 40%;
}

.div-block-233 {
  height: 50%;
}

.div-block-234 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="section-8">
    <div class="div-block-230">
      <div class="div-block-233">
        <div>
          Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc
          ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet.
          Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-234">
        <div>This is some text inside of a div block.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-block-231"></div>
    <div class="div-block-232"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it here because it's better to follow. Please reproduce your case https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-egc3xx?file=index.html

Comment: Sorry I missed one css, edited it

Comment: Try giving height: 100%; to your div-block-230 class. Is that feasible or what you want?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't do what I want. Read the requirements. It needs to be 50%

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid will do the job well. The layout will be simplified:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>Top text block</div>
  <div>Bottom text block</div>
  <div>The right blue column</div>
</div>
```

With CSS grid you'll apply min 50% to the rows `grid-template-rows: minmax(50%, 1fr);` and that will give you the desired result.

Finally, we'll make the blue column to span on 2 rows. So it always occupies the full height of the container.

Here's the full solution. EDIT: Forgot `minmax(50%, 1fr)` for the second row.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50%, 1fr) minmax(50%, 1fr);
}

.blue-column {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <div>This is some text inside of a div block.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/mn927ugt/101/

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.lorem-ipsum {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.empty-div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-container">
      <p class="lorem-ipsum">
        Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit Duis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sitDuis in tellus velit. Mauris vel nunc ac mi imperdiet imperdiet. Suspendisse ultrices Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      </p>
      <p class="text">
        This is some text inside of a div block.
      </p>
    </div>
   <div class="image-container">
     <div class="image"></div>
     <div class="empty-div"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Update:**
Vertically aligned textboxes and added empty div

Comment: Theres only 1 text box in yours? Please go through the requirements

Comment: Ah you're right. So should the textboxes be split vertically or horiztonal?

Comment: top and bottom, vertical

Comment: Text boxes not 50%